# Stuck with BlueJ project

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, bluej

So, I have a project and the task is stated this way :

You need to create a class called Candidate which stores the last name of the a person running in an election, and the number of votes they got.  You should also have methods for accessing each of the fields.  At this point, there is no need for mutators on these fields, since they should not change.

Then create a class called Election which has an ArrayList of Candidate objects.  You should have methods to1) print the list of candidates and their number of votes, 2) print the number of votes a single candidate got, given his name, 3) compute the total number of votes, and 4) print the list of the candidates, the number of votes they got, and percentage of the total vote they got, along with the winner.

Example:

Candidate   Votes Received  % of Votes
Johnson 5000    25.91
Miller  4000    20.73
Duffy   6000    31.09
Robinson    2500    12.95
Ashtony 1800    9.33
Total   19300
The winner  of the election is  Duffy.

Feel free to use this as your test data

This is the code I have so far in BlueJ

```
import java.util.*;

public class Candidate 
{
   public String lastName;
   public int votes;

   public Candidate(String surname, int voteNumber)
   {
     lastName = surname;
     votes = voteNumber;
   }   
   public String getCandidateAll()
   {
    return "' " + lastName + " has " + votes + " votes " + " '";
   }
   public int getVotes()
   {
       return votes;
   }
   public String getCandidateName()
   {
       return lastName;
   }   
}
```

What I don't understand if I am supposed to pull all second names from the first class into the ArrayList or do something else. Also, the professor mentioned that in second class iterator should be used. Please, someone, help and guide throughout the process of what to do next. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a minimal class `Candidate` of just

```
public String lastName;
public int votes;

public Candidate(String surname, int voteNumber)
{
  lastName = surname;
  votes = voteNumber;
}
```

is fine.

What you also need is another `class` which has a `main` method in which you can get user entry and also to create a `List` of these `Candidates`

Once you have the `ArrayList` you can loop (iterate) through to `sum` or `search` etc.